# Enable btrfs compression while installing Lubuntu 21.10

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, btrfs, 21.10

I tried to install Lubuntu 21.10 on btrfs partition. It works, but by default compression is not enabled. Is possible to enable compression in installer, or with some parameters for installer ?

Regards.

Comment: There are many ways of achieving it. But the easiest way is to enable compression after install.

Comment: The only QA-testing with `xfs` or `btrfs` file-systems in Lubuntu is that the installs work; not the specific features wanted by end-users are available/work out of the box; as most users who want specific features usually know to achieve their aims.  A *btrfs* install is QA-tested though - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to manually inject option `compress` into Calamares before installation, and into `fstab` after installation.